# Condo seller failed to disclose water damage which caused toxic mold that made family sick.

Tags: contract-law, real-estate

I bought a condo July '16 from out of state and could not be here for the inspection although my realtor was. In the disclosure statement the seller checked 'no' regarding moisture problems or water damage, and then checked 'yes' that the plumbing and water heater are in good working order.  The inspection report photo shows that she cleaned up the heater (it's 19 yrs old), painted spots on walls, and covered floor with clutter. Since moving in, I found that she had covered obvious signs of water damage and leaks. Now, my child, my puppy, and myself are all dealing with toxic mold sickness and the lengthy process of remediation/restoration. I'm a disabled Veteran with health issues and the toxins hit me hardest. Is there a statute of limitations? Do I have a case?

Comment: based on what youve said, you should go to an attorney. sounds like they had to have known of the water problems they denied having, if there appeared to be deliberate covering up of those things.

Comment: To find out more about your legal options and what they may cost, Google for a free or low cost legal clinic in your area, or talk to an attorney who advertises free first consultations for civil cases. Some of your options will depend on the jurisdiction and those tenant, personal injury and statutes of limitations.

Answer (score 1):

We can't judge whether you have a case (i.e. whether you can establish in a court of law that seller knew of the condition, had an obligation to disclose, and the condition caused you harm): your attorney can inform you about your prospects. Assuming that you are in California, [California Civil Code 2079.4](http://law.onecle.com/california/civil/2079.4.html) states a statute of limitations

> In no event shall the time for commencement of legal action for breach
>   of duty imposed by this article exceed two years from the date of
>   possession, which means the date of recordation, the date of close of
>   escrow, or the date of occupancy, whichever occurs first.

[Section 2079.8(b)](http://law.onecle.com/california/civil/2079.8.html) says:

> ...nothing in this section increases or decreases the duties, if any,
>   of sellers or brokers, including, but not limited to, the duties of a
>   seller or broker under this article, Article 1.5 (commencing with
>   Section 1102) of Chapter 2 of Title 4 of Part 4 of Division 2, or
>   under Chapter 7.5 (commencing with Section 2621) of Division 2 of the
>   Public Resources Code, or alters the duty of a seller or broker to
>   disclose the existence of known hazards on or affecting the real
>   property.

which is to say, it's not just the broker who has a duty to disclose. If you are in some other state, the laws could be different, but probably not very different.